# Angular 2 Navigation Events

Tags: angular, routes, navigation

I have a new Angular 2 application (latest full release) and I want to know the current url and the target url each time a user navigates whether by clicking on a link or typing in the browser's address bar.  I want to be able to decide whether they are permitted to go to the url and if not put them back to the original url.  I want the url in the address bar to be updated in either case.  I've tried the following but these didn't offer the oldUrl only the NewUrl.

```
    router.events.subscribe((event: NavigationEvent) =>
    {
        if (event instanceof NavigationStart)
        {

        }

        if (event instanceof NavigationEnd)
        {

        }

        if (event instanceof NavigationCancel)
        {

        }
    });
```

I was easily able to achieve this in Angular 1 with scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, newUrl, oldUrl) and scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (evt, newUrl, oldUrl).

Please help.

Comment: Check out the CanActivate guard for determining if user is permitted to navigate. Not sure how to grab target and last url though.  https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#can-activate-guard

Comment: Thanks cboston for your reply.  I've already set up a guard with CanActivate but it doesn't give me the newUrl and the oldUrl.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following Guard, it gives the oldState and newState that contains the URLs you want. Depends on the your usecase if that helps.

```
export class PendingChangesGuard implements CanDeactivate<Shipments> {
    constructor(@Inject(ComponentService) private _service:ComponentService){}
    @HostListener('window:beforeunload')
    canDeactivate(component: Shipments,
                  currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
                  currentState: RouterStateSnapshot,
                  nextState: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
        console.log(nextState)
        return this._service.getSelectedMaterials().length < 0 ? true : window.confirm("Are you sure you want to Exit??") ;
    }
}
```